# Parsing JSON into list

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

So I was trying to parse the JSON data into list/array, but kinda stuck at the format like this.
I'm relatively new at JSON, so I'm not very good at processing those stuffs

Here's my code:

```
void processJsonData(string _url)
{
    jsonDataClass jsnData = JsonUtility.FromJson<jsonDataClass>(_url); //_url is based on the Json text below
    Debug.Log(jsnData.data);
}
```

I uses this code to see if it managed to get the data from it, but
[it shows the error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gumpy.png)

The JSON looks like this:

```
[{"country":"Malaysia","sales":9244},
{"country":"Singapore","sales":3103},
{"country":"Japan","sales":1755},
{"country":"China","sales":7835},
{"country":"United States","sales":2755},
{"country":"United Kingdom","sales":8611},
{"country":"Australia","sales":3877}]
```

My `jsonDataClass` looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
    
[Serializable]
public class jsonDataClass
{
    public List<basicData> data;    
}

[Serializable]
public class basicData
{ 
    public string country;
    public float sales;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**
Apparently in Unity you can not directly deserialize collection/list/array with the built-in [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) (thanks to @derHugo for the info), if you looking for quick *and probably dirty* solution, use below code:

```
List<basicData> jsnData = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<basicData>>("{\"data\":" + _url + "}");
```

And if you like to learn more, see: [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36239705/3367974) and [JSON Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)

Comment: tried the 1st one, still having the same error, is there any other way? Or there's nothing much i can do besides on changing the json?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, but I saw this solution too: `JsonUtility.FromJson<List<basicData>>("{\"data\":" + _url+ "}");`

Comment: The first solution (and also the last) doesn't work in Unity (see [JSON Serialization -> Supported Types](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)) .. you can't directly deserialize collections with the built-in JsonUtility .. rather than answering with a solution from a duplicate answer rather actually vote to close the question as a duplicate

Comment: @derHugo I didn't copy my answer from another answer/source, I'm not familiar with Unity, I just post my idea based on C#, as you can see in the edit history, I added link of the related question ~10 min after posting my answer.

Comment: Yes so at that point you knew that there is a duplicate question with a lot kfoe and more detailed answers already ;) Still, and in particular if you are not familiar with the Unity API: The Serialization of something like `List<T` or `T[]` isn't supported .. it's simply **wrong** and misleading ;) => This reduces your answer to the wrapping of the JSON Data .. which is ok-ish but as said .. the duplicate already provides way better and more detailed solutions